# Magento 2 disable Secret Key on URL's from terminal

Tags: magento2, travis

Given I don't have GUI access to Magento, is there any command that I can run to be able to disable the secret key add for the URL's from terminal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this in magento's installation directory:

```
bin/magento config:set admin/security/use_form_key 0
```

Or if you use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun):

```
n98-magerun2 config:store:set admin/security/use_form_key 0
```